# Execution of bash script differs when runned from Matlab and Terminal

Tags: matlab, ubuntu

I have a bash script and I want to execute it from Matlab 2014b in Ubuntu 14.04. When I launch it from terminal (that I start from os) everything is ok. I try to launch it from Matlab like this

```
!./script.sh
```

It executes but cannot open image files that have to be loaded.
More than that if I launch terminal window from Matlab

```
!./gnome-terminal
```

and use it to launch the script I got the same 'file not found' problem. Text files are accessed with no problem. Path to the images are global. To load images opencv library is used. My guess is that for some reason opencv works different from Matlab, but I don't know what to do.

I spend a lot of time to figure out the problem, but still cannot resolve it. I will appreciate any advise or help.

Comment: Are you using absolute paths for your image files? Perhaps you are inside the wrong directory

Comment: The Matlab shell is not necessarily the same shell as your terminal shell.  Check to make sure that any required options from your `.profile` or `.bashrc` are not missing.  For example the path or an alias.

Comment: Thank you, Matt! I wasn't able to figure out the problem by looking in .profile and .bashrc, but I compared environment variables of 2 terminals (Matlab and Ubuntu) and have found that they differ a lot. I did
setenv('LD_LIBRARY_PATH', <content of LD_LBIBRARY_PATH from Ubuntu terminal>);

And now it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LD_LIBRARY_PATH of Matlab shell differs from one of teminal shell. Following command in Matlab:

```
setenv('LD_LIBRARY_PATH', <content of LD_LIBRARY_PATH from terminal>)
```

solves the problem.
Content of LD_LIBRARY_PATH from terminal is printed by

```
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```